# SQL server is disabled when trying to connect database to .net

Tags: sql-server-2005

Generating user instances in SQL Server 2005 is disabled when I am trying to connect my database to .net. I used `sp_configure ' user instances enabled'` to generate user instances.
What should I do?

Comment: ya i got the answer....
 To fix this, please Open the SQL Server Management Studio Express. This is the downloadable program in the same site where you downloaded the SQL Server 2005 express used to manage SQL Server 2005 Express.
In the query editor type this text: exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1.
Then type: Reconfigure.
Then restart the SQL Server database.

Comment: Please post your answer as *an answer* and not a comment using the "Answer your question" button below. You can then accept this answer in two days.

Comment: I've you post an answer, flag and I'll delete mine

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, please Open the SQL Server Management Studio Express.

This is the downloadable program in the same site where you downloaded the SQL Server 2005 express used to manage SQL Server 2005 Express. In the query editor type:

```
exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1
```

Then type

```
 Reconfigure.
```

Then restart the SQL Server database